# How to await for the post data before the page meta head property in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-meta

I'm using Nuxt SSR to dynamically inject the [head property](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-head) to set page level meta data. The data is fetching from Firebase. I'm getting property undefined because it doesn't wait for the post data finish loading. How do I wait for the post data before the head property?

```
client.js?16a3:97 TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
```

```js
// page\:post.vue
<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default {
  fetch() {
    this.fetchPost()
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('posts', ['post']),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('posts', ['fetchPost']),
  },
  head: {
    title: this.post.title,
    link: [{ rel: 'canonical', href: this.post.canonical }],
    meta: [
      { hid: 'name', itemprop: 'name', content: this.post.title },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        itemprop: 'description',
        content: this.post.content,
      },
    ],
  },
}
</script>

// store\posts.js
export const state = () => ({
  post: null,
})
export const mutations = {
  setPost(state, payload) {
    state.post = payload
  },
}
export const actions = {
  async fetchPost({ commit }, key) {
    const doc = await postsCollection.doc(key).get()
    if (doc.exists) commit('setPost', doc.dat())
  },
}
```

Comment: why are you using the store, do you need the same head meta info everywhere?

Comment: I'm using the store to manage states which feed to multiple components. Home page and miscellaneous pages meta are handled globally via nuxt.config.js. I'm using page level head meta for the posts pages which are user generated content for SEO purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you construct the head (object) could be changed to be a function.

```js
head() {
    return {
        title: this.post.title,
        link: [
            { rel: 'canonical', href: this.post.canonical }
        ],
        meta: [
            { hid: 'name', itemprop: 'name', content: this.post.title },
            {
                hid: 'description',
                itemprop: 'description',
                content: this.post.content,
            },
        ],
    }
}
```

I read a similar post on GitHub [here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1086). Since you are using the store I assume you are also using the asyncData function to fetch them.

Comment: Using the head method helps, but it still doesn't wait for `this.post` to populate before running the code. Is it possible to watch for `this.post` to become `!null` then run this code?

Comment: You could add post to your watchers. That should update when the value changes. You can read more about watchers [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#watchers).

Comment: I tried watchers like this `watch: {
    post() {
      this.head()
    },
  },` but it didn't work. Because head method run on first page load, and watchers doesn't trigger `head()` to rerender the meta. Have I done something wrong here with the watchers or somehow observe `this.post` before executing the head method?

Comment: You should be ok with the way you watch the post variable. But you have to set a variable in that method instead of running `this.head()`. You made it so that head was async, you should put a `await` in front of the variable in your head that needs to wait. For example, in the return of the head, you have to wait for the title that would make: `title: await this.post.title`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Your first answer works perfectly. Simply change the `head: {}` to `head() {}` works well without need to use the watcher.